# How to implement Debug for serde::ser::Error

Tags: rust, serde

I am writing a custom Serializer for serde.
For it, I also need a custom error type.
Serde requires me to implement `serde::ser::Error` for this.
`serde::ser::Error` in turn requires me to implement a `custom()` method where the parameter is only limited by the `std::fmt::Display` trait bound.
So I came up with this:

```rust
use std::fmt::{Debug, Display, Formatter};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Error {
    Custom(Box<dyn Display>),
    CannotSerializeMap,
}

impl Display for Error {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Self::Custom(error) => Display::fmt(error, f),
            Self::CannotSerializeMap => write!(f, "cannot serialize map"),
        }
    }
}

impl std::error::Error for Error {}

impl serde::ser::Error for Error {
    fn custom<T>(msg: T) -> Self
    where
        T: Display,
    {
        Self::Custom(Box::new(msg))
    }
}
```

However, I cannot derive `Debug`, which is necessary for `std::error::Error` which in turn is necessary for `serde::ser::Error`, since `Box<dyn Display>` does not implement `Debug`.
I cannot implement `Debug` for it, since neither `Box` nor the trait `Debug` itself are in my crate.
I also cannot add an appropriate constraint for `T` in `custom()` since it would break the trait's contract.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You can implement `Debug for Error` instead of deriving it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a little trick, based on two facts:

- Everything that implements `Display` also [implements `ToString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/alloc/string/trait.ToString.html#impl-ToString-for-T) (by formatting the value with `Display` into the empty string).
- One can create a `Box<dyn Error>` from `String` [with a `From` implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/alloc/string/struct.String.html#impl-From%3CString%3E-for-Box%3Cdyn+Error%3E).

Therefore, whenever you have some `T: Display`, you can instead of `Box<dyn Display>` get a `Box<dyn Error>`, like this ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=457fe46a98adff730fa638f20e5343ba)):

```
use std::fmt::{Debug, Display, Formatter};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Error {
    Custom(Box<dyn std::error::Error>),
    CannotSerializeMap,
}

impl serde::ser::Error for Error {
    fn custom<T>(msg: T) -> Self
    where
        T: Display,
    {
        Self::Custom(msg.to_string().into())
    }
}
```

And then `#[derive(Debug)]` works out of the box (pun unintended), since `dyn Error` is `Debug`.

Comment: At this point, why not just store `String`? It's both cheaper and allows for more functionality. Of course, you may want to work with the original type, but then this trick doesn't work anyway.